# MySQL Date comparison returning null

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a problem regarding MySQL where I try to compare a Date to a string. I am fiddling around on phpMyAdmin to create the correct SQL query before implementing it on my website where the string would represent the WHERE clause parameter.

I have a table called 'bookings' which has a column called 'Check In' which has Date set as its data type. One entry has its 'Check In' date set to '2013-12-12'. I planned to post images of the structure and entries but can't due to my starting reputation.

I have browsed around and tried various variations both found on StackOverFlow and other sources such as:

```
SELECT * FROM `bookings` WHERE DATE_FORMAT('Check In',  '%Y-%m-%d' ) = STR_TO_DATE('2013-12-12', '%Y-%m-%d')

SELECT * FROM `bookings` WHERE 'Check In' = STR_TO_DATE('2013-12-12', '%Y-%m-%d')

SELECT * FROM `bookings` WHERE 'Check In' = DATE_Format('2013-12-12', '%Y-%m-%d')

SELECT * FROM `bookings` WHERE 'Check In' = '2013-12-12'
```

All of these return 0 results even though I have an entry with a date of 2013-12-12. This is my first post ever on stackoverflow and excuse myself if anything is ambiguous but none the less thank anyone trying to help.

Comment: If you didn't name your column with spaces, you wouldn't need to quote it, and then you wouldn't run into the problem of using the wrong kind of quotes.

Comment: Yes you are right its a common naming convention mistake I make when creating a DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'Check In'` is just string value so, string 'Check In' is converted to "0000-00-00".

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('Check In', '%Y-%m-%d');
+-------------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT('Check In', '%Y-%m-%d') |
+-------------------------------------+
| NULL                                |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+--------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                              |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Incorrect datetime value: 'Check In' |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

To reference column names, `Check In` is used. could you try this?

```
SELECT * FROM `bookings` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`Check In`,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) = STR_TO_DATE('2013-12-12', '%Y-%m-%d')

SELECT * FROM `bookings` WHERE `Check In` = STR_TO_DATE('2013-12-12', '%Y-%m-%d')

SELECT * FROM `bookings` WHERE `Check In` = DATE_Format('2013-12-12', '%Y-%m-%d')

SELECT * FROM `bookings` WHERE `Check In` = '2013-12-12'
```

Comment: Thanks this solved everything. Changed Check In to CheckIn and it works fine. Thanks